# AWS managed ECS Fargate capacity provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

We are planning to create ECS Fargate cluster.

Now we want to use AWS managed capacity provider for ECS cluster.

I am using below template to create cluster and capacity provider for fargate.

```
Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
Properties: 
  ClusterName: dev-cluster
  DefaultCapacityProviderStrategy: 
    - Base: 1
      CapacityProvider: FARGATE
      Weight: 1
```

Now in DefaultCapacityProviderStrategy we have below three items

```
  "Base" : Integer,
  "CapacityProvider" : String,
  "Weight" : Integer
```

But my concern is we dont want to create any capacity provider so what to provide in CapacityProvider ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CapacityProvider` is optional, and you don't have to explicitly specify it. If its not given, `FARGATE` provider is by default. You need to only specify `CapacityProvider` if you want to add `FARGATE_SPOT` to your setup.

Update:

```
Resources:

    ECSCluster:
        Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
        Properties:
            ClusterName: dev-cluster
            CapacityProviders:
                - FARGATE
```

Comment: If i dont provide any capacity provider in fargate how it will increase no of task if there is more load?

Comment: @AWS_Beginner `FARGATE` is used if you don't provide any. There is no difference between you explicitly writing `FARGATE` in your `CapacityProvider` and not giving it at all.

Comment: I tried providing ```FARGATE``` as capacityprovider but it says ```specified capacityprovider cannot be given in capacity provider statergy because its not associated with cluster``` . I am very confused should i give ```CapacityProviders``` or ```DefaultCapacityProviderStrategy``` in cloudformation

Comment: @AWS_Beginner I don't know what you tried. Your question does not show any valid CFN code.

Comment: Updated CFN in original post

Comment: @AWS_Beginner I updated the answer. If you want to use FARGATE it should be as I wrote.

Comment: Thanks. It works. One question if we keep ```FARGATE``` like above. Does it takes care of scaling of task automatically?

Comment: @AWS_Beginner Yes. Fargate is serverless, just like lambda.